# C redirecting pointer

Tags: c, pointers, redirect

I have some function that receives a pointer to a char[].

```
void foo(char *number, int size)
{
  char tmp[size];
  for(i=0;i<size;i++) //We look to see if the array number points to contains a 1
    tmp[i] = (number[i]=='1'?'1':'0');//if not then add a 0.

  *number = &tmp; //PROBLEM LINE

  printMyPointer(number); //some function to print the contents of the array pointed to.
}
```

But I am having the hardest time redirecting my pointer. I thought this example would read as "change pointer to this address". But I receive a compiler warning that "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]". How should I be redirecting my pointers?

Comment: It should be `*number = tmp`. Arrays behave similar to pointers

Comment: v3ga, *number = tmp; returns the same warning.

Comment: Actually it's `number = tmp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array name in `c` is a pointer to its first element. You should use:

```
number = temp;
```

This will immediately fix the issue, neglecting any other thing in code. Your output is wrong because you are not appending a null character end of `number` string. Try:

```
for(i=0;i<size-1;i++) //We look to see if the array number points to contains a 1
    tmp[i] = (number[i]=='1'?'1':'0');//if not then add a 0.
tmp[size-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: This still won't work since tmp is created on the stack and hence will go out of scope as soon as the function returns.

Comment: printMyPointer(number); is called when tmp is still under scope. printMyPointer(number); is not being called from main(). The best way to check- RUN IT.

Comment: You're right. But then there's no use of doing `number=tmp`. You could as well do `printMyPointer(tmp)`.
Why `number=tmp`?

Comment: I'm not supposed to write better code for the op. I can just correct them. And the op wrote it that way

Comment: I assumed the intention of `number=tmp` is that the OP intends number to point to the modified value after the function returns.

Comment: Sorry! I couldn't understand that

Comment: Why would you change the loop bound?  Presumably, the loop is supposed to iterate `size` times.  Rather, the `tmp` array should be `size+1` elements to accommodate the NUL terminator, which should be placed at `tmp[size]`

Comment: To create space for the null character.